# Como modificar lo que se muestra en el campo loupe de gvnix?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jpa, gvnix

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con spring roo y con gvnix, la duda que tengo es sobre el campo **loupe**, ya se como cambiar lo que se me muestra en el listado de resultados de la busqueda, concatenando los campos de mi entidad que quiero y llamandolos con el tag **onDrawFunction**.
Ahora cuando selecciono uno de los resultados de la lista quiero se coloque en el input tal y como aparece con todo y la concatenacion pero solo se coloca el primer campo que es el aparece por default

este es el codigo del field loupe en mi **create.jspx**:

```
<loupefield:loupe  additionalFields="nombre,apellidoP,apellidoM,curp" caption="nombre" controllerPath="dictamens" field="perito" id="c_com_avance_periciales2_domain_Dictamen_perito" listPath="peritoes/list" mode="create"  searchField="alert()"  onDrawFunction="onDrawNombrePerito" path="/peritoes" pkField="id" z="user-managed"/>
```

este es mi codigo en el loupe-callbacks.js

```
function onDrawNombrePerito(oData){
   return oData.curp + " - " + oData.nombre + " " + oData.apellidoP+ " " + oData.apellidoM;
}
```

Habra algun tag o funcion ya definida para esta operacion? o tendre que modifcar los javascript que ya estan creados automaticamentes por el framework **gvnix** y asi decirle al js lo que quiero que aparesca en el input al seleccionar uno de los resultados

Comment: Hola! ¿Podrías indicar la versión de gvNIX que estás utilizando? Dependiendo de la versión podré validar si esta funcionalidad está disponible o sería necesario una personalización de los ficheros JS.

Comment: es el **gvNIX-1.5.1.RC4**